# Setting up a script to access separate database

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-connection

I have a websites A and B for different stores. They have separate databases, though almost the same products. The products which are the same are with the same item code, but different IDs.

The problem is I need to access website B's database using website A's page.

Question 1: Is this kind of script possible? The script will be on website A, and as it gathers necessary data, it will access some of website B's database tables. I think it is possible but I am not 100% sure.

Question 2: How is a script like this written? My idea is to make a file for website A with access permission and information for website B's database.  I'm just not sure how to go about making this happen.

By the way, both websites A and B are in EC-Cube CMS. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To access other database on you query use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM databaseName.tablename
```

I hope this helps.